# Unable to resize image using CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to resize my image using my CSS as i have to code different css for different media query. So this is the various methods i found on this stackoverflow and tried to resize my image on CSS.

First i tried inserting div.

```
<div id="images"><img src="image/s1.jpg" name="slide"></div>
```

CSS

```
#images{
width:100%;
height:150%;
}
```

But it didn't change.

Secondly, i used class

```
<img src="image/s1.jpg" name="slide" class="images">
```

CSS is the same as the top

```
#images{
width:100%;
height:150%;
}
```

The other CSS of mine on the same page works fine just that it doesn't work for images. Is there any way i have left out to resize my image with the CSS?

Comment: When you set dimensions based on percentage, it's calculated based on the element's parent, so its parent element has to have the dimensions set as well, or it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.images` class selector, `<img src="image/s1.jpg" name="slide" class="images">`

```
.images{
  width:100%;
  height:150%;
 }
```

instead of

```
#images{
  width:100%;
  height:150%;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are targeting the container element, not the `img` tag, and hence your `img` won't resize, so use this

```
#images > img {
   /* Styles */
}
```

*Secondly, i used class* but you are still using `#images` which is an `id` selector so you need `.images` `.` which is a `class` selector and not `#` .

```
.images {
   /* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
#images > img {
    width:100%;
    height:150%;
}
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4hkWX/)

**Whats happening** : you have assigned the css to the `div` tag, its should be for the `img` tag of the div.So `#images > img` would assign it to the `img` tag of the div!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#images img {
  width:100%;
  height:150%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
For the first case use:

```
#images > img {
  width:100%;
  height:150%;
}
```

For the second case use:

```
img.images {
  width:100%;
  height:150%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
  <div>
<img src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSqqEKVYrUqwTWgHCUeV26xUokzezlKVjlf6S9tV0fIvgMF_oR4"
name="slide" id="images" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#images{
width:100%;
height:150%;
}
```

[DEMO HERE..!!](http://jsfiddle.net/Aj52P/2/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Aj52P/6/ see in the first css you are applying style to the id and not images so i added the id to the images.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case of css

```
#images{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

you are just adjusting the size of the `div` in which the image is present.

Note that you have used an id `#images` here in first case

In the second case of css
you are adjusting the size of the image but using a class "images" instead of id

so either

```
#images img{
  width:100%;height:150%;
}
```

for the first case would do.

or

```
.images{
      width:100%;height:150%;
    }
```

for the second case.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you're just resizing the `div`. In the second example, the `img` element has a `class` attribute, but the CSS contains an `id` selector. Either assign the image an `id` attribute with value "images" (assuming you only have one image you want to style),

```html
<img src="image/s1.jpg" name="slide" id="images">
```

or alter the CSS to use a `class` selector rather than an `id` selector (for styling many images):

```css
.images {
    width:100%;
    height:150%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making a background-image on `div` this also. It's useful.

```
<div class='images'></div>
```

---

css code:

```
.images{
width:100px;height:100px;
background-image:url('yourimage.jpg');background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Resize it as you wish (: